# How do I see branches on local repo? Adding files

Tags: git, bitbucket

As you would have guessed I am new to git. I want to add a new image file to my branch example

main >hhd (branch) - however in my local finder window I cannot see the branch folder. I can only see folders from the main repo.

Also how do I add a file into this folder?

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't fully get the concept of git version control, but that's okay.

Depending on the IDE you are using or cmd you can switch between branches in various ways.

If you have never used git before I would recommend using Github Desktop which is a Client for git (it is a different thing from Github, you can still use it with your bitbucket repo).

Now, you are not going to find a folder with branches and individual different projects en each of those branches. Instead when you switch between branches of a project, you are switching between entire workspaces. So the folder from the main repo you see, is the one that belongs to the current branch. When you switch branches the project will also switch.

So now you need to checkout your branch, which just means selecting it on Github desktop and drag your picture into the desired folder. Your changes are going to appear on Github Desktop, then you just need to commit and push them to the repo.

Comment: Thank you Berta - I will try that. :) Cheers

Comment: So I guess I got the concept of switching the branches using the cmd prompt. How I am in correct folder. However I need to add a file to that folder from a local machine and the file is in /downloads folder. What would be the command to add this file to the branch I am in right now? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I am using Mac and Bitbucket :)

Comment: You can drag and drop it using Finder as you would move any other file from the downloads into the folder. Git will notice these changes inside the repo. After that you just need to commit and push your changes to the origin repo (bitbucket).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to download and install sourcetree for Simplicity and power in a beautiful Git GUI.

it's very easy to switch between branches, Push, Pull with GUI

https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/